# A free tool to find grants from IRS 990s?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, irs

At the beginning of 2016 the IRS finally opened up their electronically filed 990 forms from nonprofits (see [article](https://sunlightfoundation.com/2016/06/16/irs-opens-up-form-990-data-ushering-nonprofit-sector-into-the-age-of-transparency/) from the Sunlight Foundation). All of the 990 data is now machine-readable and uploaded by the IRS to Amazon Web Services.

Amazon [provides instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/irs-990/) on how to interact and procedurally use this data trove, however I can't seem to find any free website that has actually done this.

Right now the only way I know of how to find who a Private Foundation has given money to is:

1. Tediously read through each Foundation's actual IRS 990-PF form and
   look at each grant recipient.
2. Pay for a subscription (starting at
   $200/mo?) from FoundationCenter.org to use their database.

Does anyone else know of any other ways or a free database that's already been created from all of the data that the IRS placed on AWS?